# c# if statement inside while loop how to break out if user inputs valid data

Tags: c#, while-loop, break

I would like to know what to put in the if statement brackets to tell the program, if x or y equals a double, it can break out and continue carrying out the rest of my code.

Any suggestions?

```
while (true)
{                    
    Console.Write("I need to pour this much from this one: ");

    string thisOne = Console.ReadLine();
    Double.TryParse(thisOne, out x);

    if ( /* Here I want to put "x is a number/double*/ )
    {
        break;
    }

}

while (true)
{
    Console.Write("I need to pour this much from that one: ");

    string thatOne = Console.ReadLine();
    Double.TryParse(thatOne, out y);

    if (/* Here I want to put "y is a number/double*/)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: My suggestion is to read the [documentation for `Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx).  Hint:  It returns a boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TryParse returns a boolean to say whether the parse was successful

```
if (Double.TryParse(thatOne, out y))
{
    break;
}
```

From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

> A return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed.

Answer (score 2):

`Double.TryParse` returns a boolean, perfect fit for your if statement

```
if (Double.TryParse(thatOne, out y)) {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a misconception about TryParse(). You want to check if x is a double. somewhere above in your code, you did not post it here there is probably a line like `double x = 0;`.
You defined x and y already as double. You want to check if your input which is string can be parsed to double:

The shorthand version is  this:

```
if (Double.TryParse(thatOne, out x))
{
    break;
}
```

This can also be written as:

```
bool isThisOneDouble = Double.TryParse(thisOne, out x);

if (isThisOneDouble)
{
    break;
}
```

If you really want to check if a variable is of certain type without trying to parse it, try it like this:

```
double x = 3;
bool isXdouble = x.GetType() == typeof(double);
```

or

```
double x = 3;
if(x.GetType() == typeof(double)) 
{
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Control your loop with a bool, set the bool false when your condition is met...

```
bool running = true;
while (running)
{                    
    Console.Write("I need to pour this much from this one: ");

    string thisOne = Console.ReadLine();

    if (Double.TryParse(thisOne, out y))
    {
         running = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like an unnecessary step? This also requires the loop to perform a full iteration, the OP might want to break out early.

Comment: It also doesn't answer the question of what goes into the if statement.

Comment: Just edited to include, missed that from the original question. The last step is a break so not adding extra execution.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), TryParse returns true if parsing succeeded so just put your tryparse into your if statement.